# Random Array generation

Tags: java, initializer

I am trying to create an array and have it filled with 0 or 1's randomly throughout the array. Below you will find the code. I am very new to java so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private static void randHouse() {
    int rows = 4;
    int columns = 5;
    int i = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int [][] myList = {
            {0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0}
    };
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myList)); // just prints the array

    for (i : rows); {
        for (y : columns);{
            myList[i][y] = (int)random() * 10;
        }
    }
}
```

I am currently getting the error :
java: bad initializer for for-loop

Comment: For loops do not work like that but like `for(int i=0;i<rows;i++;){` (note that there is no semicolon before the `{`, too). See [the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easiest (imo) to use streams.

```
int r = 4;
int c = 5;
int[][] result = randHouse(r,c);
for (int[] row : result) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

Prints something like

```
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

- The `IntStream` iterates over the rows
- the inner rand call generates each row of 1's and 0's.
- then they are combined into an array of arrays.

```
private static int[][] randHouse(int r, int c) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    return IntStream.range(0, r)
            .mapToObj(i -> rand.ints(c, 0, 2).toArray())
            .toArray(int[][]::new);
}
```

Note:  In your original problem, `(int)Math.random()*10` will first convert the random value to 0 and then multiply by 10. So all you get are zeros.  If you did the following `(int)(Math.random()*10)` you would get a value between `0` and `9` inclusive.  Instead of `10`, you should use `2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
        myList[i][j] = (int)random() * 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: This generates a matrix of all 0's.